# Computer Receiving WAN IP instead of LAN IP

Tags: networking, router, lan

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on. I recently purchased a Netgear CM400 cable modem and a Netgear N300 router.

I was able to successfully configure my CM400 with Time Warner Cable, my internet provider and successfully connect while having my laptop plugged directly into the cable mode.

I then hooked up my N300 router and after a couple hours of messing with it was able to get internet across my LAN. However, the catch is my IP Address on my local machines is being reported as my WAN ip provided from TWC, not my local IP provided from the router, which prevents me from accessing the router admin page.

I've tried even statically setting my local IP to that of what would be assigned by DHCP on the router to no avail, the connection dies and nothing works.

I have no idea how to fix this - would appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you access the admin page with the cable modem disconnected from the router? Maybe you switched the router to some bridge only mode (so now it acts like a switch). In that case you would probably need to reset it; OR connect it and your PC to another router (well, if you have one), then access the admin page with the IP it has configured/been assigned with (IF it still got the admin page up in that mode; you can check that on the client list on the other router).